# Res.redirect doesn't redirect to the URL but passes website as response

Tags: node.js, express

```
exports.Auth = async (req, res, next) => {

  const state = req.query.state
  const email = req.body.email.toLowerCase();
  const password = req.body.password;
  let loadedUser;
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ email: email });
    if (!user) {
      const error = new Error('A user with this email could not be found.');
      error.statusCode = 401;
      throw error;
    }
    loadedUser = user;
    const isEqual = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    if (!isEqual) {
      const error = new Error('Wrong password!');
      error.statusCode = 401;
      throw error;
    }
    const token = jwt.sign(
      {
        email: loadedUser.email,
        userId: loadedUser._id.toString()
      },
      process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY,
      { expiresIn: '1000h' }
    );
    res.redirect(301, 'https://google.com');

  } catch (err) {
    if (!err.statusCode) {
      err.statusCode = 500;
    }
    next(err);
  }
};
```

Tried the following :

res.redirect('https://www.google.com')
res.status(200).redirect('https://www.google.com')

But nothing worked, what am I doing wrong?

I tried using Postman and it shows the webpage as a response but the browser does not redirect.

Comment: How do you send the request in the browser?

Comment: This is a post request : localhost:8080/auth, the user enters username & password, and the server is supposed to authenticate and generate a token and then redirect to another page.

Comment: Using an html form or fetch or axios?

Comment: Using an HTML Form